# Не получается запустить более 4 потоков URLDownloadToFile

Tags: c++, распараллеливание

Имеется такая функция, которая нужно выполнять одновременно в 100 потоков.

```
void tryURL()
{
    randURL.clear();
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < urlLength; i++) {
        randURL = randURL + alphabet[getRand()];
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(URLDownloadToFile(NULL, LPCWSTR((beginURL + randURL + endURL).c_str()), LPCWSTR((randURL + L"/" + endURL).c_str()), 0, NULL)))
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), GREEN);
        wcout << L"Downloaded! " << endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), WHITE);
    }
}
```

Распараллелил так:

```
while (1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; ++i) {
        thr[i] = thread(tryURL);
    }
    cout << "100 threads done" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; ++i) {
        thr[i].join();
    }
    cout << "100 threads joined" << endl;

}
```

Но при этом эта функция не посылает более 4 запросов одновременно. Может, где то надо отключить лимитирование по ядрам процессора? Уже переломал всю голову, никак не могу найти в чём проблема. С источником рандома всё нормально, используется системный.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А у Вас на процессоре 100 ядер?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, дело не в потоках, а в ограничениях используемого сетевого стека.

В `WinInet` (а `urlmon.dll`, в которой реализована функция `URLDownloadToFile`, использует именно её) есть [лимит на число одновременных соединений с сервером](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/183110/wininet-limits-connections-per-server).

По умолчанию этот лимит равен 2 для HTTP 1.1 и 4 для HTTP 1.0.

Исправить ситуацию можно руками, вызвав при старте приложения примерно такой код:

```
void FixMaxConnsPerServerLimit()
{

  DWORD maxConns = 100;

  InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER, &maxConns, sizeof(DWORD));
  InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_1_0_SERVER, &maxConns, sizeof(DWORD));
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не изменилось. Сначала ввёл как предложили вы, пришлось подключить Wininet. Потом попробывал через UrlMkSetSessionOption, тоже самое. Может быть, мне стоит по другому скачивать файлы? Мне нужно, в основном проверять их наличие, скачка файла происходит редко.

Comment: @megapro17 Можете использовать wininet [напрямую](http://rsdn.org/article/inet/wininet.xml).

Comment: Я понял, в чём стоит лимит. Wininet не даёт открыть больше 4 handle одновременно. Как это обойти?

Comment: @megapro17 Так, код в ответе именно про это.